# loadFiles is not a function discord.js v14 error

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I already made `loadFiles` as a function but this issue still persists.

Code for `fileLoader.js`:

```
const { glob } = require('glob');
const { promisify } = require("util");
const proGlob = promisify(glob);

async function loadFiles(dirName){
  const Files = await proGlob(`${process.cwd().replace(/\\/g, "/")}/${dirName}/**/*.js`)
  Files.forEach((file) => delete require.cache[require.resolve(file)]);
  return Files;

module.exports = { loadFiles }

}
```

Code for `eventHandler.js`:

```
async function loadEvents(client) {
  const { loadFiles } = require("../Functions/fileLoader.js");
  const ascii = require("ascii-table");
  const table = new ascii().setHeading("Events", "Status");

  await client.events.clear();

  const Files = await loadFiles("Events");

  Files.foreach((file) => {
    const event = require(file);

    const execute = (...args) => event.execute(...args, client);
    client.events.set(event.name, execute);

    if(event.rest) {
      if(event.once) client.rest.once(event.name, execute);
      else
        client.rest.on(event.name, execute);
    } else {
      if(event.once) client.once(event.name, execute);
      else
        client.on(event.name, execute);
    }

    table.addRow(event.name, "✅")
    
  })  

  return console.log(table.toString(), "\nLoaded Events")
}
```

Error is the following:

```
const Files = await loadFiles("Events")
                    ^
TypeError: loadFiles is not a function
```

And just if anyone asks, I've already made an events folder.

Comment: You cant export a function inside of itself. Move `module.exports...` to the outside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Elitezen said you can not export a function from within the function. Consider the following revisions:

`fileLoader.js`

```js
const { glob } = require('glob');
const { promisify } = require("util");
const proGlob = promisify(glob);

module.exports = async function loadFiles(dirName){
  const Files = await proGlob(`${process.cwd().replace(/\\/g, "/")}/${dirName}/**/*.js`)
  Files.forEach((file) => delete require.cache[require.resolve(file)]);
  return Files;
}
```

`eventHandler.js`

```js
async function loadEvents(client) {
  const loadFiles = require("../Functions/fileLoader.js");
  const ascii = require("ascii-table");
  const table = new ascii().setHeading("Events", "Status");

  await client.events.clear();

  const Files = await loadFiles("Events");

  Files.foreach((file) => {
    const event = require(file);

    const execute = (...args) => event.execute(...args, client);
    client.events.set(event.name, execute);

    if(event.rest) {
      if(event.once) client.rest.once(event.name, execute);
      else
        client.rest.on(event.name, execute);
    } else {
      if(event.once) client.once(event.name, execute);
      else
        client.on(event.name, execute);
    }

    table.addRow(event.name, "✅")
    
  })  

  return console.log(table.toString(), "\nLoaded Events")
}
```